# VS2010 Coded UI Tests vs. Web Performance test (Whats the difference??)

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2010

Been playing with both for a couple hours.

You use a Coded UI test to record some actions and verify them through assertions..

You use a Web Performance test to record some actions and verify them through validation tests/extraction tests... basically same thing... then you can convert to code optionally like the Coded UI Tests

But it seem you can only add a WEB PERFORMACE TEST to a loadTest...

But arent they both pretty much the same thing?? What am I not understand?? Why not allow a Coded UI Test to be inside a load test?

Comment: @user193189: please put hyphens ("-") between words in a compound word when making a tag. "visual-studio-2010", not "visual studio 2010".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think this [article](http://www.anitpatel.net/2011/06/03/this-is-my-second-post/)  has a great value on this discussion

> CodedUI Tests –
>   Coded UI tests are for automated functional testing. These tests will simulate user interaction against the UI, such as button clicks and entering text. Coded UI tests require an interactive desktop environment, because they actually interact with the windows and objects of your application. Coded UI Tests in VS2010 are the equivalent of using something like HP QuickTest Pro or Selenium to drive your automated functional regression tests.
>
> Web Performance Tests -
>   Web testing has much more than GUI testing. Web Performance Tests are used for testing the functionality and performance of the web page, web application, web site, web services, and combination of all of these. Web Performance Tests can be created by recording the HTTP requests and events during user interaction with the web application. The recording also captures the web page redirects, validations, view state information, authentication, and all the other activities. It can be classified in two ways which includes Simple Web Performance Tests and Coded Web Performance Tests.
>
> Simple Web Performance Tests generate and execute the test as per the recording with a series of valid flows of events. Once the test is started there won’t be any intervention and it is not conditional.
>
> Coded Web Performance Tests are more complex but provide a lot of flexibility. These types of tests are used for conditional execution based on values. Coded web tests can be created manually or generated from the Web Performance Test recording.
>
> Load Tests-
>   Load tests record and drive your application at the HTTP level. These tests simulate headless user interaction against your app server by sending HTTP requests directly, without a UI. Load tests typically assume that your application works correctly for 1 user, but aim to see if it functions under a heavy user load. Load tests are headless because simulating thousands of users with an interactive UI is not practical. By being headless, a single load agent machine can simulate hundreds or thousands of users. VS load tests are the equivalent of using HP LoadRunner or JMeter to drive virtual user load.
>
> Conclusion
>   Functional and performance testing are two distinct types, with different strategies and processes. On a given project, you might have hundreds of automated functional tests (coded ui, for example), but only dozens of automated performance tests. You have so many more functional tests because you are testing your app in many different scenarios relative to your business requirements. Whereas with performance tests, you take your top dozen most commonly used transactions and run them under load.

Answer (score 13):

Coded UI tests are for automated functional testing. These tests will simulate user interaction against the UI, such as button clicks and entering text. Coded UI tests require an interactive desktop environment, because they actually interact with the windows and objects of your application. Coded UI Tests in VS2010 are the equivalent of using something like HP QuickTest Pro or Selenium to drive your automated functional regression tests.

Load tests record and drive your application at the HTTP level. These tests simulate headless user interaction against your app server by sending HTTP requests directly, without a UI. Load tests typically assume that your application works correctly for 1 user, but aim to see if it functions under a heavy user load. Load tests are headless because simulating thousands of users with an interactive UI is not practical. By being headless, a single load agent machine can simulate hundreds or thousands of users. VS load tests are the equivalent of using HP LoadRunner or JMeter to drive virtual user load.

Functional and performance testing are two distinct types, with different strategies and processes. On a given project, you might have hundreds of automated functional tests (coded ui, for example), but only dozens of automated performance tests. You have so many more functional tests because you are testing your app in many different scenarios relative to your business requirements. Whereas with performance tests, you take your top dozen most commonly used transactions and run them under load.

Answer (score 1):

Coded UI tests are new to 2010.  They validate against the actual UI (placement in the DOM, visibility etc.) of the application where the other does not.  The Web Performance Test validates against the HTTP/HTTPS connection against the server.

This talks about functional UI testing and shows the use of the Coded UI test.

http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/10-4/10-4-Episode-18-Functional-UI-Testing/

Comment: I see.. But why not allow load tests on coded UI tests?

Is there any changes in Load Tests/Profiling from VS2008-->VS2010 ?

Comment: Is there a FAQ for Load testing/Profiling ?   

I only work on small projects so I don't have to worry about too much data for the server.. But it would be interesting to simulate many users and see what class method is taking up alot of time.. or what page..

Comment: Well probably two reasons.  1.  You don't need to test the load on the UI as it will a copy of it for each person.  2.  It's not really necessary to test load on a server, and would take up processor time and memory on the machine running the load test agent.

Comment: Is it possible to run the profiler on a LOAD TEST?  Ive been trying to do it now and it just starts and opens IE and waits for me manually to do some things and close it .. But I want the profiler to profile the LOAD TEST. 

Im not clear on your answer to #1... Are you saying Coded UI tests are really just made for testing values in the DOM as the user performs actions on the DOM?? While Web Performance tests are about going from page to page .. and its not really about testing for client side errors.. that sort of thing ?

Comment: I tihnk I got it!!   Profiler is for the actual code running on a single machine single user  and what piece of code is slowing you down... and load tests is for a web application and how scaling affects your web app.... so it doesnt really make sense after all to profile a LOAD TEST..

Answer (score 1):

Good news, from VS2012 you can add coded ui test into Load Test.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468125.aspx