# VS2010 Coded UI Test vs Web Performance Tests

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, automated-tests

I know this question looks a lot like this one, but I don't have enough rep points to comment seeking further clarification [VS2010 Coded UI Tests vs. Web Performance test (Whats the difference??)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568713/vs2010-coded-ui-tests-vs-web-performance-test-whats-the-difference)

Tom E. gives a great explanation, but I'm still a bit vague on one point. I see why Coded UI tests cannot be replaced by Web Performance tests (the extra resources needed for a browser interface) but why can Web Performance tests not replace Coded UI tests?

If you record a webperf test and generate the code from that, couldn't you add validation and extraction rules (inspecting the DOM) to achieve the same result as a Coded UI test *without* the overhead of the browser?

I realize that this wouldn't be *exactly* the same as testing in different browsers, but is there a reason this wouldn't at least test whether you're receiving the appropriate response from the server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dave, good point. I think you would see the difference fairly quickly if you were trying to build an automated functional test suite (think 500 tests or more) with VS web performance tests and having to parse the DOM for querying and interacting with the application. You would essentially be writing your own Coded UI test playback mechanism. You *could* do it without the Coded UI test functionality, but it would be quite painful. The level of pain would be dependent on how many test cases you need to automate and how many screens there are in your app and how complex the interactions are.